# WordPress > WP_List_Table > Select all checkbox doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress

I am tired, but there is no solution.. I am using WP_List_Table WordPress API, Everything is working fine, Pagination, Bulk actions but when I click on checkbox (Select All) doesn't work.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

help of others,,, I fixed this issue... I was using wp_die(); at end of function where I was writing admin page code.... so footer libraries were not written... Maybe I will helpful for others in future.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution, but I really doubt someone will face the same issue :) As I already stopped by to comment, here's how I use wp_die: `wp_die( sprintf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $my_var, true ) ) );`, cheers!